# Is there a better way of assigning ngModel?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-ng-if

I only want to use ngModel if the variable exists such as below. If the variable `app` does not exist then I don't want to include it in my model. I figured below is the easiest way to do that but is there a better way I can bind my model without checking for `app` for each element and therefore duplicating everyone?

```
<input id="phone" *ngIf="app" [(ngModel)]="app.phone" [textMask]="{mask: phoneMask}" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
<input id="phone" *ngIf="!app"                        [textMask]="{mask: phoneMask}" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `app` at the container level and use the properties inside the container if app exists like below:

```
<div *ngIf="app">
    <div [(ngModel)]="app.phone"></div>
    <div [(ngModel)]="app.address"></div> 
    <div [(ngModel)]="app.pin"></div>
</div>
```

Hence you won't have to repeatedly check for `app` at every element!

Comment: This kind of helped. Basically the context is if `app` exists then the forms inputs will have the contents of the `app` object. But if  `app` does not exist then the form will be blank. I was kind of thinking maybe `if (app) then ngModel=app.whatever else don't assign ngModel`. Something along those lines.